# Asp.net SQL How to stop the user reserving a 'place' where there are no available seats

Tags: sql, asp.net, vb.net

I currently have it so that a user can reserve a seat, and the number in the database reduces by one via an SQL query.  However,  I can't figure out how to stop the user from reserving a seat when the number is at 0.

```
UPDATE Route 
        SET NumOfSeats = NumOfSeats - 1  
        WHERE ([Origin] = @Origin) and destination = @destination and DepartTime=@time
```

When the number of seats is at '0', the user is still able to reserve a place therefore bringing number of seats to '-1'.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: For  this query, try  modifyng your 'WHERE" to include 'and numofseats>0 ' For the solution to the problem, you're going to need to test for the numofseats condition before you attempt the reservation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could add the condition that `NumOfSeats` must be > 0:

```
Dim sql = "UPDATE Route " & vbCrLf & _
          "NumOfSeats = NumOfSeats - 1 " & vbCrLf & _
          "WHERE ([Origin] = @Origin) and destination = @destination and DepartTime=@time " & vbCrLf & _
          "AND   NumOfSeats > 0"
Using con = New SqlConnection("Connection...")
    Using command As New SqlCommand(sql, con)
        command.Parameters.Add("@Origin", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Origin
        command.Parameters.Add("@destination", SqlDbType.Int).Value = destination
        command.Parameters.Add("@destination", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = time
        con.Open()
        Dim numUpdated As Int32 = command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If numUpdated = 0 Then
            ' tell user that no seat is available  ' 
        End If
    End Using
End Using
```